# C# - Set image in menu generated as mdiwindowlistitem

Tags: c#, image, window, mdi, toolstripmenu

I rewrite the question.
In C# I have a desktop application in .NET Framework. That application has a form that is MDIParent, and inside it will display a number of other forms. These forms have a visible icon in their upper left corner.

Now, the main MDIParent form has a menu bar that contains a Windows menu that will display the open windows. However, when displayed in the menu bar, the form icon does not appear. What is the best way, or ways, to get the form icon to be displayed?

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean "in C#"? there are many different frameworks in C# language. is it a WPF project? is it .NET Core? .NET framework? .NET MAUI?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I rewrite the question. Sorry.